# installed findbugs plugin on eclipse but can not see and use it,why?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I installed the findbugs plugin on my "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers",then eclipse auto restarted.
But I can not see the findbugs except in the "About Eclipse - Installation Derails"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are your OS,Eclipse version and Findbugs version?

Comment: OS is Windows 7,Eclipse version is Juno(For javaEE),Findbugs version is 2.0.2.At last I reinstall the eclipse and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC it is a bit tricky to open the Findbugs view. I think you have to enable Findbugs on per-project level at the Properties and it will open up a customized properties view or something. See the details [here in the docs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html).

Comment: Every view contributed by the plugin should be listed in the `ShowViewDialog`,but he didn't.

Comment: At last I reinstall the eclipse and fix it.

Comment: Hm... That's strange. Anyway, glad to hear. Btw it could be a possible bug, if you find some relevant info in the *workspace/.metadata/log* file, you could file a bug report on the project site.